# Input scanf array with recursively function without loops (.c)

Tags: c

The user get me the size of the array, and i am allocate with function "MALLOC" the memory allocation and get input the array with recursion only, without loops!!

I do not know how to create a "loop" with recursion function.

I hope happy to get help please.

thanks.

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you are asking, can you please clarify ?

Comment: I need input from user size of array and create allocated memory this array. And scanf to this array the values. I write this function but this not worked.


<br/>`void getss(int array[], int size)
<br/>{
    int counter=0;

 if(size==0)
  return;

 if(counter<size)
 {
  scanf("%d",&array[i];
  counter++;  
 }

 getss(array,size-1);
}`

Answer (score 1):

That's not a good use of recursion - a loop is more "natural" in this case - but the idea would be a function like this:

```
void getInput(int howMany)
{
  if (howMany == 0)
    return;
  // get user input
  getInput(howMany-1);
}
```

Comment: i agree with you, but is require of my lecturer.  but i need create a memorey allocetion, i dont need send the point of the function?

Answer (score 1):

Because this seems like homework, I'll give a homework-oriented answer -- in pseudo-code.

```
define loop(array, index)
    if index == 0
        return array
    array[index] = get input from user
    loop (array, index-1)
```

Call it with `loop(array, array_size)`.

I'd like to echo Mat's sentiment that this is not a good use of recursion.

**Update**

Since you'd like to use `scanf(3)` to read the input, I'll give a stronger hint on how to use it. Above, I wrote:

```
    array[index] = get input from user
```

You could write this line with the following `scanf(3)` call:

```
scanf("%d", &array[index]);
```

This will store a decimal integer into the `array[index]` location -- the `&` returns the *address* of the array slot, rather than evaluating the array subscription.

Comment: i need the scanf input from user values in the array. i dont understand how can i to scanf input without the loops.

Comment: +1 You're putting more effort into this than the OP deserves.